# Postman Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain after adding .pem certificate

Tags: postman, ssl-certificate

I am trying to generate a token. It is just that I am getting
Warning: Self signed certificate in certificate chain
and this error is not letting me generate a token.
I have turned off SSL certificate in the Settings as well. Also added CA certificate .pem file in the certificates section. But this is not working in any way.
Can someone help me a this.
Also, this is only causing issue in one env, other one is working rather fine.
Attached screenshots

[SSL certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbDJO.png)

[CA Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMVik.png)

I have turned off SSL certificate in the Settings as well. Also added CA certificate .pem file in the certificates section. But this is not working in any way.
Can someone help me a this.
Also, this is only causing issue in one env, other one is working rather fine.
Attached screenshots

Comment: Are you sure you added a certificate? The screenshot looks like you added a csr?
certificate_signing_request.PEM

Comment: isn't .pem file a certificate. How should I add a certificate then

Comment: a pem file COULD contain a certificate. I'm just wondering if it is a certificate based on the name of it. How did you generate the certificate and what files did it create?